# Unable to update Kotlin variable in inside the function

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to build a tic tac toe game for android.

But when I'm trying to change the active game.

The value of the variable activePlayer doesn't change

```
fun buSelect(view:View){


    var butSelected = view as Button
    var callID = 0
    when(butSelected.id){
        R.id.bt1 -> callID = 1
        R.id.bt2 -> callID = 2
        R.id.bt3 -> callID = 3
        R.id.bt4 -> callID = 4
        R.id.bt5 -> callID = 5
        R.id.bt6 -> callID = 6
        R.id.bt7 -> callID = 7
        R.id.bt8 -> callID = 8
        R.id.bt9 -> callID = 9
    }

    //The Problem go from here
    var player1 = ArrayList<Int>()
    var player2 = ArrayList<Int>()
    var activePlayer:Int = 1

    fun PlayGame(callID:Int, butSelected:Button){

        if (activePlayer == 1){
            butSelected.text = "X"
            butSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pink)
            player1.add(callID)
            activePlayer = 2
        }else{
            butSelected.text = "O"
            butSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
            player2.add(callID)
            activePlayer = 1
        }

        butSelected.isEnabled = false

    }
    // until here
    PlayGame(callID, butSelected)
    }
```

And the testing result is this:

[image: Test the code]

Comment: What variable??

Comment: activePlayer can't change after if statement

Comment: Please show your test and test result. i.e. How did you call the function? How did you read the result? What result did you get?

Comment: @RickyMo wait I will upload the result

Comment: @RickyMo Done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to move the `var activePlayer:Int = 1` outside of the function `buSelect(view:View)` think that you need it as a global variable.